# Combine SSMS and sql-management-studio tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms) and [sql-management-studio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio) tags both refer to the same application: SQL Server Management Studio.  As a result there's no need to keep both tags around.

While 21 questions in each here doesn't give either tag priority, checking other SE sites shows:

Stack overflow has 940 for favor of [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms) and ~200 for specific versions; and 219 for [sql-management-studio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio).

Serverfault has 114 for [msql-ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/msql-ssms), 18 for [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms), and 20 for [ssms-2008](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms-2008); however only [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms) has a tag wiki entry. [sql-management-studio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio) doesn't exist at all as a tag there.

DBA.SE has 118 questions for [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms) and none for any other variants.

Comment: Is there any way to use the tag markup, but link to the tag page for another SE site?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

SSMS is used much more heavily elsewhere across stack exchange, so I suggest going the other direction by merging and synonymizing [sql-management-studio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio) → [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms).

Answer (score 2):

I would propose merging and synonymizing [ssms](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssms) → [sql-management-studio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-management-studio).